# OAuth2 User Info in Chrome Identity API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-oauth

I am working with Google Chrome Identity API, i get successfully the access token and i send it to my backend Server.

To validate the access token i am using this URL :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxxxx
```

I need to get the `userId` of the authenticated user, how i can do it?

I am using this scopes in the manifest.json file.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution :

When i ask for an access token in the `interactive mode` i got the `userId` (`Sub` parameter), but if i do it in `interactive = false` mode the response have no `sub` parameter.

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
  // code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The response to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxxxx` includes the `userId` as the `sub` value.

```
{
 "azp": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "sub": "114233674199568482864",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
 "exp": "1436369027",
 "expires_in": "3589",
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

Alternatively you can make a request to [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) and use the `id` value.

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/gLREuMULAxw3wiBcudkUCAWTcjE\"",
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "114233674199568482864",
 "displayName": "Abraham Williams",
 ...
}
```

Comment: Yes when i request the userInfo endpoint= `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=xxxxxx`, the response doesn't contain the `userId` but when i ask the access token in **interactive mode** i got it !, thanks @abraham